# Add 13 to string using ASCII (And leave other characters like !@> and spaces alone)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I have to write a rot13 program in python 3.7 using ord() and chr().

I've tried doing some code saying: 
    for letter not in     "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz": 
    newLetter = letter
This essentially means that if there is a different character that isn't a letter (like ! or @ or #) to keep the character as the same thing. I don't have a clue on why the entire word isn't working and it stops early.

```
def rot_13(string):
    length = len(string)

    for letter in string:
        number = ord(letter)
        newNumber = number + 13
        newLetter = chr(newNumber)
        string = string + newLetter
   return string[length:]

print(rot13('Hello World'))
```

For example, "Hello World!" should output "Uryyb Jbeyq!" I get "Uryy|-d|yq" instead...

Comment: You get this because you don't check for "overflow".. For example: the ASCII code for 'o' is 111. 111 + 13 = 124. the character with ASCII code 124 is '|'. when you add 13, you need to check if the code you got is bigger than the ASCII code of 'z', so you can return back to 'a', and get the corresponding character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should do what you want. Basically you need to know if the letter is upper-case or lower-case (standard ROT13 cipher works only with 26 uppercase letters of alphabet).

```
legal_chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def rot_13(s):
    rv = ''
    for letter in s:
        if letter not in legal_chars:
            rv += letter
            continue
        a = ord('A') if letter.isupper() else ord('a')
        rv += chr(a + (ord(letter) - a + 13) % 26)
    return rv

print(rot_13('Hello World!'))
```

Prints:

```
Uryyb Jbeyq!
```